# How to update the value for each rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am working on a Rails project. Recently I have added an validation to a model. Below is the validation.

```
class Hub < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property, class_name: 'Property', foreign_key: :property_id
    validates :property_id, uniqueness: { allow_nil: true }
```

But in most of the places we are using @property in rspecs.
Eg:let(:hub) { FactoryGirl.create(:hub1, property: @property) }. So all the rspecs got failed because of the validation. But I need the validation. What is the efficient way to resolve all the failing rspecs.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, if you can move the `let(:hub) {FactoryGirl.create(:hub1, property: @property)}`
next to where you are creating @property probably in before hook for all test cases, with that use FactoryGirl.build instead of create(in case if you need to persist the hub inside the testcase). By doing this you can use that hub in all your testcases.

And if there are more than one hub in single testcase then I think you will have to create new property record.